# How to make the name of my app and the title bar in my main activity different?

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, intentfilter, titlebar

I'm trying to set specific name - "APP" to my app and different title to my main activity  - "Main Title", but I end up having both "Main Title".

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/main">

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>                    

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: @humazed meaning my app name is the same as my main activity title bar name. but anyways i got a good answer! thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"         
    package="com.testapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Main Title"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter
                android:label="APP">

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked, please accept the answer as the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

in your main activity write `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title you want to set")` if its extend from AppCompatActivity in case of Activity write `getActionBar().setTitle("Title you want to set")`

Comment: i hvn't tried it cos the 1st reply was correct but ur answer seems appropriate as well, so thanks :)